# Angular ng-repeat modal dialog does not work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, meanjs

I am using MEANJS, where angularjs is my front-end. i have a list of my articles, i am bring bringup a modal to edit data but fails to do so and modal does not work. i am using angular UI bootstrap for modal. my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrohitk/cwn56s1n/5/).

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="order in orders | limitTo:5">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open(order)">Edit {{ order.title }}</button>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>{{ order.title }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p ng-repeat="orde in order.orderfood">
      {{orde.name}} {{orde.qty}} {{orde.price}}
    </p>
      </div>
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
myApp.factory('Orders', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('https://safe-depths-4702.herokuapp.com/api/orders/:orderId', {
    orderId: '@_id'
  }, {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    }
  });
}]).controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $modalInstance, Orders) {
  $scope.order = Orders.get({
    orderId: $stateParams.orderId
  });

  $scope.ok = function(order) {

    $modalInstance.close($scope.order);
  };

}).controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal', 'Orders', function($scope, $uibModal, Orders) {
  $scope.orders = Orders.query();
  $scope.name = 'Superhero';
  $scope.open = function(size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        order: function() {
          return $scope.order;
        }
      }
    });
  };
}]);
```

my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrohitk/cwn56s1n/5/).

Comment: The reason your popup dosent work is because when you do ng-click()..  you pass a parameter order... Order is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an error coming from the ui-bootstrap script in your fiddle, and it may have had to do with the fact that you were injecting the correct and up-to-date `$uibModal` service but the out-of-date `$modalInstance` service.

[I created a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/32vTJLsVdsXnvmnUHGae?p=preview) with your code and updated the `$modalInstance` to `$uibModalInstance`, and the modals are working as they should.

As you have written it, you fetch an array of all the orders with your `$resource.query` method and set the array on $scope in your html. There is no need to query again in the modal; since you're already iterating through the `$scope.orders` in your `ng-repeat`, you can just pass in the order that you want to open in your `ng-click` function: `ng-click="open(order)"` and match the parameter passed into the function in your controller (which in your fiddle is `size`, not `order`). You can resolve the selected order's value and inject it into the modal's controller, rather than running a redundant query on that specific order from within the modal's controller. You were putting only the size as the `ng-click` function parameter, which you can add back in if you like... I pulled it out for simplicity's sake.